# Promise and async

Tags: node.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

function a() {
  return Promise.resolve('a')
}
async function b() {
  return Promise.resolve('b')
}
async function c() {
  return 'c'
}
console.log(a())
console.log(b())
console.log(c())
```

I got the following output for the above program.

```
$ ./main.js
Promise { 'a' }
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { 'c' }
```

But the output for `b` is different from that shown in the following video (shown as `Promise { 'b' }`).

https://youtu.be/RXN7169vBGw?t=138

Could anybody help me understand why there is such a difference? Has nodejs changed since the video published?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it depends on NodeJs version. If you use recent version >= v10.x.x, it outputs `Promise { <pending> }`. Maybe on the tutorial the guy uses v8.x.x.